# I need to select multiple strings that match a patindex from a single string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, patindex

I need to select multiple strings from a single string in that match a patindex. I am selecting the first one using the following code:

```
CASE WHEN comments like '%[0-9][A-Z][0-9].[0-9]%'
  THEN SUBSTRING(comments,PATINDEX('%[0-9][A-Z][0-9].[0-9]%',comments),5)
  END AS 'Code'
```

The pattern is number, letter, number, '.', number

Each of the strings that I need to select can be in any position in the string.

Here is an example string: 5D3.5,SLV,4F2.5,4DR,12/03

I need to select 5D3.5 and 4F2.5 from this string. These will all be random and different and need to use the patindex. There are not always commas separating.

Answer (score 0):

**Your (2) Problems :**
You have a string with a series of values delimited by comma. Then you want to select only some of those values based on specific criteria.

**Parsing**:
You need to first parse the entire string and extract such values.
Study this solution [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

**Selecting**:
After you solve problem one, this will be a simple select using LIKE.